# Matlab add text to the outside of figure

Tags: matlab, text, figure

How do I add a text to the right of the figure? I want to resize the plot to leave some empty space on the right and add some information there.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 16):

If you want to put that text inside of a legend you can do:

```
legend('Some quick information','location','EastOutside')
```

That is easiest. For more control though, you can put a text box inside the figure window:

```
MyBox = uicontrol('style','text')
set(MyBox,'String','Here is a lot more information')
```

and move it around with:

```
set(MyBox,'Position',[xpos,ypos,xsize,ysize])
```

Comment: very nice conclusion about text formatting for MATLAB plots: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/creating_plots/adding-text-to-graphs.html

Comment: The `uicontrol` text won't work for 3D axes, will it?

Answer (score 4):

Try this for short text:

```
plot(1:5);
text(5.05, 2.5, 'outside', 'clipping', 'off');
```

Or this solution for more complex annotations:

http://radio.feld.cvut.cz/matlab/techdoc/creating_plots/chaxes6.html