# Matlab text object carriage return issue + text outside graph

Tags: matlab, text, uicontrol

I'm trying to show some text on top of a plot. Using

```
text(13,15200,('~ 12h'),'HorizontalAlignment','right','VerticalAlignment','middle','FontSize',10,'FontAngle','italic');
```

I can create the text box how I want it. But a thing I didn't manage to do is to create a carriage return within that text object. Already tried to add '\r' or '\n' but the only thing I get is the display of '\r' or '\n' with out breaking the line. Any ideas?

And i now that text object are used to put text WITHIN axes. But I am still trying to find a way to put some text outside the grap. Searching stackoverflow I found this [Post about using UICONTROL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525890/matlab-add-text-to-the-outside-of-figure). It works great but when I export to EPS the text seems to be in pixel format and NOT vector - so it looks really bad. Is there another way besides using uicontrol??

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In text that is not interpreted, you can specify line breaks using the carriage return character, which has the ascii code 10.

```
text(x,y,sprintf('break after this%snew line here',char(10)));
```

To allow text outside axes, you need to turn off clipping for the text object

```
text(x,y,.....,'clipping','off')
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I don't know whats wrong but your hint with using '%s' for carriage return doesn't work for me. The text for the second line just doesn't show up (I am on Matlab 2009 maybe thats the reason). But luckily when combining the use of sprintf and '\n' I get the carriage return =) And of course the clipping off thing does exactly what I want. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @ranzbert: Oh, I forgot to add `char(10)` in my answer :)