# How to write A on the top of the boxed axis over the point (1,80) as shown by the figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

```
x=0:0.1:10;
y=1.85;
z=x.^(y);
plot(x,z);
```

How to write A on the top of the boxed axis over the point (1,80) as shown by the figure?[image]

Comment: See MATLAB's [`text`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) function. Maybe something like `text(1, 82, 'A')`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matlab add text to the outside of figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525890/matlab-add-text-to-the-outside-of-figure)